# Similarity distance measures

Tags: vector, data-mining, similarity, hamming-distance

Vectors like this

```
v1 = {0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1}
v2 = {0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0}
v3 = {0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1}
```

Need to calculate similarity between them. Hamming distance between `v1` and `v2` is 4 and between `v1` and `v3` is also 4. But because I am interested in the groups of '1' which are together for me `v2` is far more similar to `v1` then `v3` is.

Is there any distance metrics that can capture this in the data?

The data represent occupancy of house in time, that's why it is important to me. '1' means occupied, '0' means non occupied.

Comment: so what is the question ?

Comment: sorry, already edited, if there is any distance metrics that can capture this

Comment: `I am interested in the groups of '1' which are together`. Could you explain what you mean by that? 1 and 2 are more simliar because of the same _amount_ of groups?

Comment: well basically yes, 1 and 2 are more similar there is same amount of groups. Because `v2` is basically vector `v1` only with the `first group` of '1' being "wider". `V3` is almost empty vector

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you need [**cosine similarity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) measure:

```
similarity = cos(v1, v2) = v1 * v2 / (|v1| |v2|)
```

where `v1 * v2` is dot product between `v1` and `v2`:

```
v1 * v2 = v1[1]*v2[1] + v1[2]*v2[2] + ... + v1[n]*v2[n]
```

Essentially, dot product shows how many elements in both vectors have 1 at the same position: if `v1[k] == 1` and `v2[k] == 1`, then final sum (and thus similarity) is increased, otherwise it isn't changed.

You can use dot product itself, but sometimes you would want final similarity to be normalized, e.g. be between 0 and 1. In this case you can divide dot product of `v1` and `v2` by their lengths - `|v1|` and `|v2|`. Essentially, vector length is square root of dot product of the vector with itself:

```
|v| = sqrt(v[1]*v[1] + v[2]*v[2] + ... + v[n]*v[n])
```

Having all of these, it's easy to implement cosine distance as follows (example in Python):

```
from math import sqrt

def dot(v1, v2):
    return sum(x*y for x, y in zip(v1, v2))

def length(v):
    return sqrt(dot(v, v))

def sim(v1, v2): 
    return dot(v1, v2) / (length(v1) * length(v2))
```

Note, that I described similarity (how much two vectors are *close* to each other), not distance (how *far* they are). If you need exactly distance, you can calculate it as `dist = 1 / sim`.

Comment: I believe it should be `dist = 1 - sim` and not `1 / sim`

Comment: @ThalisK.: both will work. The idea is that distance is in some sense inverse of similarity, so any inverse (and strictly monotone) function should work, and you can select concrete function based on your concrete interpretation of "distance".

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I would appreciate it if you would then take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181104/cosine-distance-as-vector-distance-function-for-k-means

Comment: if i have more than three vectors,
like if i want to check v4 is different from v1, v2, and v3, can i apply your answer?

Comment: Cosine similarity is a pairwise distance measure, so you can use it to any number of vectors as long as you consider their pairs (e.g. `v4` vs `v1`, `v4` vs `v2`, etc.). If you want a measure that works with 3 or more vectors _at the same time_, you should be more specific about desirable properties of this measure. E.g. you may want an average distance of `v4` from `v1`, `v2` and `v3` and that is as easy as `(dist(v4, v1) + dist(v4, v2) + dist(v4, v3)) / 3`. So it all depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Any reason why your length function does not account for the sqrt? `|v| = sqrt(v_1^2 + v_2^2 + ...) =/= v_1^2 + v_2^2 + ...`

Comment: You've just got a badge for watchfulness :) I've edited the code, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are literally hundreds of distance functions, including distance measures for **sets**, such as Dice and Jaccard.

You may want to get the book "Dictionary of Distance Functions", it's pretty good.

Comment: Looked up the title and didn't find it. Could your provide author, isbn, exact title please?

Comment: First result on Google Books. ISBN: 9780080465548

Comment: The book is a great reference. It has been updated and renamed as Encyclopedia of distances: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-52844-0

Answer (score 1):

> Case 1: IF the position of the ones in the series is relevant, THEN:

I recommend Dynamic Time Warping Distance (DTW). In application of time-series data it has proven incredibly useful.

To check whether it can be applied to your problem, I used the code presented here: https://jeremykun.com/2012/07/25/dynamic-time-warping/

```
d13 = dynamicTimeWarp(v1,v3)
d12 = dynamicTimeWarp(v1,v2)
d23 = dynamicTimeWarp(v2,v3)

d23,d12,d13
(3, 1, 3)
```

As you see, d12 is lowest, therefore v1 and v2 are most similiar. Further information of DTW can be found anywhere in this forum and for research papers, I recommend anything by [Eamonn Keogh](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/).

> Case 2: Position of ones is not relevant:

I simply agree Deepu for taking the average as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply take the average of the values in each set. For example `v1` here will have an average **0.4545**, average of `v2` is **0.6363** and average of `v3` is  **0.0909**. If the only possible values in the set are 0 and 1, then the sets with equal or nearly equal values will serve your purpose.

Comment: That's actually good idea, the problem I have though is that I have to mix the two metrics somehow together. Because vectors `0 0 1 1 ` and `1 1 0 0` would with average return both `0,5` and with my metrics `4` that all of them are displaced. Is it possible to somehow combine these two metrics that each yields half of the final  value? Or is that too unpredictable?

Comment: What about Standard Deviation? Will it help?

Comment: In a way I guess if the distribution below it was gaussian. But if I again take the the `0 0 1 1 ` and `1 1 0 0 ` example the **std** will have same results. I know how you mean it but then I would have to first cluster it make means of the clusters and then compare means and std of each cluster. But if such a complicated solution makes significant different.

Answer (score -1):

There is a web site introducing the various type of vector similarity methods

http://dataaspirant.com/2015/04/11/five-most-popular-similarity-measures-implementation-in-python/

I think it will help you to decide what similarity you should use

.

.

Briefly explaining the above link, there are five popular similarity measurement between vectors

1. Euclidean Distance - Simply the absolute distance between the vectors
2. Cosine - Cosine degree(theta) difference between the vectors
3. Manhattan -the sum of the absolute differences of their Cartesian coordinates, for example,

> In a plane with p1 at (x1, y1) and p2 at (x2, y2). Manhattan distance
>   = |x1 – x2| + |y1 – y2|

4. Minkowski - generalized metric form of Euclidean distance and Manhattan distance
5. Jaccard - Similarity between the objects. So each feature in one set will be compared to another set and finds out its difference

.

With the keyword above you can google for further explanation.
Hope it would help you